# how to get text representation from XDocument?

Tags: linq-to-xml

XmlDocument class has a property "Text" whicn allows you to get text representation of XML (that is only the text part collected within all the nodes), how do I get it from XDocument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
string text = doc.Root.Value;
```

?

Comment: thanks, let me try that, looks like it is what am looking for, I thought value represents only current text value of element, not its decendents, but I saw msdn it is what I am looking for.

Comment: @bdares: I can't reproduce that. Maybe you should ask a new question, with a short but complete example in it.